# Passing local storage data from chrome extension to content script automatically on every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an chrome extension, which saves user input to the local storage via `chrome.storage.sync.set/get...` and sends this data via `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` to a content script, which listens via `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`. This whole *load and send* process is triggered, when the user opens the extension per mouse click and presses a button. Before this happens the content script has not the needed data to do its task and is waiting.

### Concrete requirements / questions:

- I want, that the local storage data gets loaded (and sent to the content script) automatically on every page load without any user interaction needed.
- Which callback do I have to implement or where do I have to put my code in order to achieve this?

The whole code looks like this (*Tag* and *Pass* are the mentioned user data):

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var tag = document.getElementById(DOM_TAG).value, pass = document.getElementById(DOM_PASS).value;
    // ...query for the active tab...
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            from: 'popup',
            subject: 'init',
            tag: tag,
            pass: pass
        });
    });
    // Save data to local storage.
    chrome.storage.sync.set({DOM_TAG: tag, DOM_PASS: pass}, function() {
        // Notify that we saved.
    });
}
// Once the DOM is ready...
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Load data from local storage.
    chrome.storage.sync.get({DOM_TAG: 'defaultTag', DOM_PASS: 'defaultPass'}, function(items) {
        document.getElementById(DOM_TAG).value = items.DOM_TAG;
        document.getElementById(DOM_PASS).value = items.DOM_PASS;
    });
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

### What I already tried:

Of course I tried to start the process inside the `callback` function for `DOMContentLoaded`, but that is not working since this event only gets fired when the user manually opens the extensions by clicking on it. Thats not what I want.

I also tried to put the specific lines of code into a `BackgroundScript`, with no success.

Comment: Where is this code located?  In a content script?  In a background script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to pass data from extension to content script. You can access it directly in content script. i.e: `chrome.storage.local` and `chrome.storage.sync` are available to content scripts.

> Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.

[`storage` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)